# Solving $u = xu_x + u_t$ by method of characteristics

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm learning the method of characteristics. Suppose we want to find

$$u(t,x)$$

such that

$$u = xu_x + u_t$$

$$u(0,x) = f(x)$$

By the multivariable chain rule, and putting the PDE again below to compare:

$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{dt}{dt}$$

$$u = xu_x + u_t$$

By comparsion we get:

$$\frac{du}{dt} = u \rightarrow u = K_1e^t$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x \rightarrow x = K_2e^t$$

So, at the path $(t,K_2e^t)$ we have that $u$ is $K_1e^t$. But there is a family of paths $(t,K_2e^t)$ because $K_2$ is undetermined. Let's see the graph for one possible $K_2$:

[image]

If I knew $K_2$ then I'd have this path in the graph, and then I'd know that on this path, $u(0,K_2) = f(K_2) = K_1$ so the solution for $u$ on the path $(t,K_2e^t)$ should be $u = K_1e^t = f(K_2)e^t$. However this solution is not for every $x$ and every $t$, it's just in the path, that is:

$$u(t, K_2e^t) = f(K_2)e^t$$

there's still work needed to generalize it for $u(t,x)$ in general.

**So the two questions are: how to find $K_2$ first, and how to transform $u(t, K_2e^t) = f(K_2)e^t$ into a solution dependent of $t$ and $x$, that is, $u(x,t)$?**

Comment: $$K_{2} = xe^{-t}$$

Comment: @Mattos makes sense. Somehow I thought that the family $(t, Ke^t)$ could intercept but it looks like that they span the $xt$ plane at least for this path in particular. Can it be that this don't happen?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'the family $(t, Ke^{t})$ could intercept. If you're asking if the characteristics can intersect with each other then, for this PDE, the answer is no. But for other PDEs, the answer is yes, for example, the inviscid Burgers equation $$u_{t} + uu_{x} = 0$$ with piecewise initial data

Comment: @Mattos in this case then, method of characteristic wouldn't work?

Comment: No, it still works in the case of the inviscid Burgers equation, you just have to be careful about how the information propagates along the characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xu_x+u_t=u$$
Your approach is equivalent to considering the system of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{u}$$
A first family of characteristic curves comes from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{u}$ leading to :
$$ue^{-t}=K_1$$
A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dt}{1}$ leading to :
$$xe^{-t}=K_2$$
Thus the general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation is :
$$\Phi(K_1,K_2)=\Phi(ue^{-t},xe^{-t})=0$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.

Equivalently, expressed on explicit form : 
$$ue^{-t}=F(xe^{-t})$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$u=e^tF(xe^{-t})$$
The function $F$ has to be determined to fit the boundary condition.

CONDITION :
$$u(0,x)=f(x)=e^0F(xe^{-0})=F(x)$$
Thus the function $F$ is the same function as the known function $f$. Puting it into the above general solution leads to the particular solution which fits the boundary condition :
$$u(t,x)=e^tf(xe^{-t})$$